# How can I promote an issue from one stream to its parent via the CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, accurev

While trying to automate my process as much as possible, I would like to be able to promote an issue from one stream to another, via the CLI, in AccuRev 6.0.2

I've tried seemingly every documented example and permutation of the `accurev promote` command, to no avail. It seems that when using the `-s` switch, it isn't recognized. And when using it with the `-S` switch, an error is reported that the source stream must be specified by the `-s` switch, which it is.

I've tried specifying the issue as well, with the `-I <issuenumber> -3` from the external issue tracker, as well as with `-I <accurev issue number>` which was created from the external system, retrieved via the `accurev cpkdescribe` command. I've also tried with the external list file, in both XML and one-item-per-line, again, with both the 3rd party issue number, as well as the AccuRev issue number.

Boiled down to its simplest form, which I would have expected to work, is this command: `accurev promote -c "Move changes from DEV to QA stream" -I <issueNumber> -3`. Can this be done via the CLI, or should I resign myself to using the GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Run the command "accurev help promote"

You need to use the options below.

`-Fx -l "XML-file"`

The "XML-file" specifies a set of issue records with an XML-format text file.

Command:

```
accurev promote -s "From Stream" -S "To Stream" -Fx -l issuesToPromote.txt
```

where the file would contain:

```
<issues>
 <id>42</id>
</issues>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when promoting from one stream to another, there's the question on *what* you want to promote (and you did not specify what in you question.)

@jstanley notes the `-Fx` switch to promote by issue, but possibly, you want to promote everything, in which case you'd just use the `-d` switch:

> `-d` : Selects all elements in the default group of the workspace (or more
>   generally, the child stream).

That would become `accurev -s "from" -S "to" -d` and then all pending files, hence all pending issues, will be promoted to the parent stream.

Note: The `-I`or `-3 -I` switch is never useful when promoting from stream to stream, because you have already linked your files up to the issues when promoting from the workspace. Use `-I` only when promoting from a workspace.

If you want to promote-by-issue you must use `-Fx -l` as described in the other answer.